# Why am I getting this error when trying to use snscraper?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

The following code:

```
import time
import pandas as pd

# pip install snscrape
!pip install snscrape

# Pull Twitter data using SNScrape
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter

scraper = sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper("#python")

for tweet in scraper.get_items():
  break

tweet
```

Keeps throwing this error:

> "ERROR:snscrape.base:Error retrieving
> https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&include_ext_has_nft_avatar=1&include_ext_is_blue_verified=1&include_ext_verified_type=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_ext_limited_action_results=false&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_ext_collab_control=true&include_ext_views=true&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&include_ext_sensitive_media_warning=true&include_ext_trusted_friends_metadata=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweet=true&q=%23python&tweet_search_mode=live&count=20&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&include_ext_edit_control=true&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel%2ChasNftAvatar%2CvoiceInfo%2Cenrichments%2CsuperFollowMetadata%2CunmentionInfo%2CeditControl%2Ccollab_control%2Cvibe:
> blocked (403) CRITICAL:snscrape.base:4 requests to
> https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&include_ext_has_nft_avatar=1&include_ext_is_blue_verified=1&include_ext_verified_type=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_ext_limited_action_results=false&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_ext_collab_control=true&include_ext_views=true&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&include_ext_sensitive_media_warning=true&include_ext_trusted_friends_metadata=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweet=true&q=%23python&tweet_search_mode=live&count=20&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&include_ext_edit_control=true&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel%2ChasNftAvatar%2CvoiceInfo%2Cenrichments%2CsuperFollowMetadata%2CunmentionInfo%2CeditControl%2Ccollab_control%2Cvibe
> failed, giving up. CRITICAL:snscrape.base:Errors: blocked (403),
> blocked (403), blocked (403), blocked (403)
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ScraperException                          Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in <cell line: 12>()
> 10 scraper = sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper("#python")
> 11
> ---> 12 for tweet in scraper.get_items():
> 13   break
> 14  4 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/snscrape/base.py in
> _request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, timeout, responseOkCallback, allowRedirects, proxies)
> 245                         _logger.fatal(msg)
> 246                         _logger.fatal(f'Errors: {", ".join(errors)}')
> --> 247                         raise ScraperException(msg)
> 248                 raise RuntimeError('Reached unreachable code')
> 249  ScraperException: 4 requests to https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&include_ext_has_nft_avatar=1&include_ext_is_blue_verified=1&include_ext_verified_type=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_ext_limited_action_results=false&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_ext_collab_control=true&include_ext_views=true&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&include_ext_sensitive_media_warning=true&include_ext_trusted_friends_metadata=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweet=true&q=%23python&tweet_search_mode=live&count=20&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&include_ext_edit_control=true&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel%2ChasNftAvatar%2CvoiceInfo%2Cenrichments%2CsuperFollowMetadata%2CunmentionInfo%2CeditControl%2Ccollab_control%2Cvibe
> failed, giving up."

I am not sure why I am getting this error. At first, I thought I hit a rate limit or something and my IP was blocked so I tried it on a few different networks with different devices with different Google accounts every time I am getting the same error. Could it be something with the python or snscraper version?

Comment: If you are rate limited then by your api keys rather than your IP

Comment: There's no API key with snscrape though so that's the thing I'm not sure how else they would tack it other than IP address.

Answer (score 3):

this is because snscrape searches the Twitter data without any authentication, i.e., it searches for Twitter data without using your email, password, or authentication key.
but now, Twitter has restricted searching data without logging in to the Twitter website, i.e., if you log out of your Twitter account on the Twitter website, you will not have a search functionality there.
So, snscrape cannot extract the tweets data from the Twitter website as of now.

The Twitter functionality might change in future, or the API might improve, but as of now, scscrape is not working.

For more details, [check here](https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/issues/846)

Comment: For people looking at this now - the issue has been fixed, but the new search functionality is much more unreliable because of issues at Twitter's end.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has blocked snscrape and all scrapping tools. It has improved its own APIs. So currently snscrape is not accessing twitter. It may change in the long run.